# nginx isnt forwarding to static server

Tags: nginx

I have two servers running in the background, I would like nginx to reverse proxy to both of them.

I want nginx to run on port 80. When a user navigates to `http://localhost:80/`, he should be forwarded to `http://localhost:3501`. However I am still seeing the default nginx page at `http://localhost:80`. I have nginx installed on my localhost, and am testing from the same box.

```
server {
               listen 80;
               server_name _;

               location ^~/api/* {
                       proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
               }
               location ^~/* {
                       proxy_pass http://localhost:3501;
               }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add upstream:
   `upstream backend-testserver {

       server 127.0.0.1:3501 weight=1 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=30s; # server 1

       server 127.0.0.1:3502 weight=1 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=30s; # server 2

   }`
2. Add proxy_pass in "server -> location":
   `location / {

       root   html;

       index  index.html index.htm;

       proxy_pass http://backend-testserver;

   }`